# What are coins for in Super Mario Kart on SNES?

Tags: super-mario-kart

In the oldschool super mario kart for snes you could collect coins that lie around on the track.

What do they do? Why should I collect them?

Back in the days as a kid I would collect them because they are a shiny. I doubt that is everything to it.

[image: HUD showing 3 coins]

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Each coin held [slightly increases your top speed on the road](http://tasvideos.org/GameResources/SNES/SuperMarioKart.html), by approximately 0.8%-1% per coin (the exact percentage depends on the selected driver, the kart class, and whether you're playing a PAL or NTSC version). For example, a Koopa Troopa with 10 coins will have the same top speed as Bowser with 0 coins.

[As michaelb958 notes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166763/what-are-coins-for-in-super-mario-kart-on-snes#comment223812_166769), you only need 10 coins for the maximum speed bonus. Any additional coins will not provide further benefits.

You will lose 4 coins if are hit by an item that causes you to spin out, 2 coins if Lakitu rescues you, and 1 coin if you hit another player. If you crash into another driver while you have 0 coins, your kart will spin out.

Coins do not affect any other aspects, so [drivers are still going to vary a lot in acceleration, handling, etc.](https://web.archive.org/web/20141010130456/http://www.gdward.plus.com/site/gaming/docs/smk.txt)

Comment: Just BTW, I think coins after the 10th don't provide any further benefit.

Comment: @michaelb958 is correct. The max speed increase is 10 coins.

Comment: Never knew this, mind=blown

Comment: I read the manual for that game ( http://www.mariomayhem.com/downloads/mario_instruction_booklets/Super_Mario_Kart-snes.pdf ) SO MANY TIMES.  I was seven when it came out, and it taught me the meaning of the word "Surplus".  "Any number of coins over 10 are surplus."

Comment: @ilinamorato furthermore the manual adds: "coins only appear in the GP and MATCH RACE modes" and "Lakitu will charge you if he needs to pick you up" (Lakitu is the guy with the cloud)

Comment: Yep.  What it doesn't mention is, he'll still pick you up even if you don't have any cash to spare.  :-)  Ah, good times.

Comment: @ilinamorato seems you did not read that manual often enough. it tells you so on page 20.

Comment: @Wandang whoops, you're right.  Ah, I forgot about that!  I even had the drawing of Yoshi spinning out on that page on the front of one of my elementary school notebooks.

Answer (score 37):

Also, when a player-controlled driver is hit, they lose a coin. If a player-controlled driver is hit with zero coins, they will spin-out.

Comment: Furthermore (according to the manual linked above) if an item attack causes you to spin you lose 4 coins and Lakitu rescuing you costs 2 coins.